# Is it possible to delete messages that only I sent and only with a prefix

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to delete messages that only I and my friend sent that start with `'-'`

This is the code:

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.username == "SugarPancake" || message.author.username == "vordemolt" {
    message.channel.send("");
    await message.delete();
  } 
});
```

It deletes every message I send and not only the ones that start with '-'.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which part of the code you provided you expected to only target messages starting with a hyphen `-`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the message content.

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  var usernames = ["SugarPancake", "vordemolt"];
  if (usernames.includes(message.author.username) && message.content.startsWith("-")) {
    message.channel.send("something");
    message.delete()
  }
})
```

I made the code clearer and easier to read too.

Comment: Please click the checkmark to mark it as correct and helpful

Comment: Another note: Please use the IDs (message.author.id) of the users and not their usernames, as IDs are unique and can be better used for comparisons.

Comment: Usernames are fine for private servers though